# Can't add Orbital script - "The script needs to derive from MonoBehaviour!"

Tags: unity-game-engine, hololens, mrtk

I am developing in Unity 3D for the Microsoft HoloLens 1. I am trying to add the Orbital script from the Mixed Reality Tool Kit to a GameObject, but no matter what I do I keep getting this error message:

> "Can't add script behaviour ScreenSpaceMousePointer. The script needs to derive from MonoBehaviour!"

I don't understand why I'm getting this message, since I'm trying to add Orbital, not ScreenSpaceMousePointer. Is there any way to get around this?

EDIT: For further context, I am trying to affix an upright plane with a little map on it to the bottom right of the HoloLens display such that it follows the user wherever they turn their head (much like how a minimap looks in video games).

Comment: Is your file called `Orbital` (in the Assets), `Orbital.cs`( in the PC's Filebrowser) and the class called `public class Orbital : MonoBehaviour` ? Which version of the MRTK are you using?

Answer (score 1):

Orbital inherits from Solver which inherits from MonoBehaviour. So you should be adding it to a GameObject. It's unclear why that error message is appearing without more information.

What version of MRTK/Unity are you using?

Can you create a cube and add orbital via "AddComponent" in inspector?

Can you search for the orbital script in your assets window and drag it onto a simple cube in inspector?

Unfortunately I cannot repo your issue. You can also try looking at the SolverExamples unity scene.

[image]

Comment: I am using Unity version 2018.4.15f1 (I am working on a group project and this is the version that our team has decided upon to accommodate a different feature in the project). 

The version of MRTK I have is 2.0.0.

I am not able to find Orbital in the Add Component inspector for some reason. Perhaps I made an error when importing MRTK to my Unity project? The error message I described above happens when I drag the Orbital script from my Assets window onto my Game Object.

Comment: It is recommended that you backup your project first, and then follow this documentation(https://microsoft.github.io/MixedRealityToolkit-Unity/Documentation/Updating.html) upgrade MRTK to the latest version. If you still have the issue please provide more details about your application, such as the MVCE(stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and the steps to reproduce the issue.

Answer (score -1):

Please, show this script.
Head of it must be like this:
`class Orbital: MonoBehavior {`
And file name must be Orbital.cs

You may create this file and put inside code you need, but rename class and file to avoid duplicate class name.

Do you have errors in your project? This usually happens for a message you got.

Comment: I would prefer not to make changes to the file, as it was written by Microsoft as part of the Mixed Reality Tool Kit. The Orbital script is not my own.

Comment: I don’t know Mixed Reality, but I know Unity. Problem either with Orbital class or another error in project and this script can’t compile. As Troy said we need more information anyway.